How to check the availability zone used by a resource on Azure?
I have a Web App and a PostgresSQL flexible server running on Azure.
When creating the Postgres server, the following option is provided:

You can optionally specify an availability zone in which you deploy your database server to co-locate with your application. Learn more

screenshot:

I'd like to create Postgres in the same zone as my Web App to improve performance.
But, to do that: how to know in which availability zone the web app is located?

Where I've looked:

I've checked the dashboard for the Web App, docs, ChatGPT and Claude but to no avail.
The CLI offers the az webapp show --name your_app --resource-group your_group command but it contains zero details about zones.
Maybe cross-referencing IPs or SSH might let me deduct the zone for the web app, but if so I haven't found how.

Notes:

I am creating the PostgresSQL server separately from the Web App because that's the only way to choose the exact Postgres server I want.
I do not want to use "Zone redundancy" (because of the increased costs associated with it); I simply want to know which zone the Web App is using so that I can choose the same zone for Postgres.


It is entirely possible that your web app is not deployed into a Zone at all. Maybe you are coming from AWS and things are different there, but in Azure, a Zone is very frequently an additional level of configuration, its entirely possible to deploy everything to a region and let Azure sort out just where in that region things are deployed. If you want to set up high availability within a region, then you want to pay attention to zones and make sure your workload is replicated between two or more zones.

This is important for migration as well. It is recommended to create the flexible server in the same zone.

Expanding my comment into an answer: the Web App may not be zone-redundant. From what I can see, it is the App Service Plan that must be zone-redundant, and it is configured so at deployment time, per pictures below. Do note that deploying it as Zone-redundant means 3 instances (3x the base cost), so you don't choose the zone, you just run in all the zones available in a given region (and to make this more fun, not all regions support zones!).
At deployment time:

And this is visible via the resource explorer later:

In your situation, the correct answer, at least in my opinion, would be no preference, since your application likely does not have a preference.
And, for the sake of completeness, when an App Service Plan is not configured for zone redundancy, it looks like this:

